# jQuery tooltip onClick?

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip

I have been looking for a long time now and can't seem to find a jQuery tooltip plugin that utilizes the following:

`onClick` (Instead of `hover`, making it work like a toggle button)
Fade In/Fade Out

The idea for using tooltips is that I have a few links which I want to display content in. While normal tooltips (this is probably where I went wrong..) are for hovering, it needed to be one that was toggled by clicking on the link triggering it.

Are there better ideas for this than using a tooltip?

Comment: Why would this be voted down? It's a legitimate question with a following question asking for clarification.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know how you've been looking but a quick google search for jquery tooltip gave me
http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html (been using their scrollable plugin for some time now, really like it :)

from their site:

> jQuery Tooltip allows you to fully control when the tooltip will be
>   shown or hidden. You can specify different events for different types
>   of elements. You can control this behaviour with the events
>   configuration variable which has following values by default:

```
events: {
  def:     "mouseenter,mouseleave",    // default show/hide events for an element
  input:   "focus,blur",               // for all input elements
  widget:  "focus mouseenter,blur mouseleave",  // select, checkbox, radio, button
  tooltip: "mouseenter,mouseleave"     // the tooltip element
}
```

using 'click' should do the trick. (I didn't test it)

however, if all else fails you can still fake it by using the 'scripting api', just call .show() and .hide()

**Edit:**

Since click, click doesn't work exactly as I thought it would, I offer you a workaround.
I really hope that there's a nicer way to achieve the same result though.
I tested it with a local copy of http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html and it works as expected.

```
var tooltip = $("#dyna img[title]").tooltip({
    events: {
      def:     ",",    // default show/hide events for an element
      tooltip: "click,mouseleave"     // the tooltip element
    },
   // tweak the position
   offset: [10, 2],
   // use the "slide" effect
   effect: 'slide'
// add dynamic plugin with optional configuration for bottom edge
}).dynamic({ bottom: { direction: 'down', bounce: true } });

tooltip.click(function() {
    var tip = $(this).data("tooltip");
    if (tip.isShown(true))
        tip.hide();
    else
        tip.show();
});
```

But I suggest you take a look at qTip as suggested by user834754 as well, you might like it more.

Comment: I have looked at this one, the only thing I didn't like about it was the use of images, as I wanted to use CSS for the tooltips.

Comment: I also use this tool and you can use pure CSS for the tooltip, read the documentation more thoroughly.

Comment: Major problem with this one, there is no way to allow the tooltip to toggle. Using `click, click` for the `events:` does not work.

Comment: ok, I see what's happening here. A click seems to trigger both events at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to open a jQuery UI tooltip (jQuery UI version 1.10.2) on a click event.
Add *title* attribute to an element other than the element on which the tooltip is to be displayed.

```
<span id="helpbutton" title="This is tooltip text">Help</span> <!-- tootltip would be displayed on click on this -->
<input id="inputbox"></input> <!-- help to be displayed for this element -->
```

Initialize the tooltip on the element that has title attribute with position set to the target element.

```
$("#helpbutton").tooltip({position: {of: "#inputbox", at: "right"}});
```

Call *open* on the tooltip in the callback function of the *click* event on the target element.

```
$("helpbutton").click(function() {
    $("#helpbutton").tooltip("open");
});
```

Source : [Floating help box with jQuery UI tooltip](http://codefreakr.com/floating-help-box-with-jquery-ui-tooltip/)

Answer (score 3):

u can try use qTip, u can bind any jquery event on it:

```
show: { when: { event: 'click' } }
```

A simple and pretty plugin :) http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#show

Comment: Note that this is for version 1. For version 2 it would now be show: { event: 'click' } (http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/show/#target)

Answer (score 2):

if you prefer a simple, lightweight tooltip, you can consider http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/ then simply bind the onclick jquery event to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
$("#myTooltip").tooltip().off("mouseover").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).attr("visible") === "1") {
    $(this).attr("visible", "0");
    return $(this).tooltip("close");
  } else {
    $(this).attr("visible", "1");
    return $(this).tooltip("open");
  }
}).on("mouseleave", function(event) {
  return event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Comment: It worked for me. I spent some time on this problem, and stopImmediatePropagation() method saved my day!.