# How do I make qTip2 for jQuery work only on click?

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I am using the qTip jQuery plugin, and want the tooltip to appear only when clicking a link or button. I have found several methods that are supposed to work, but don't seem to work in practice. Here is a jsFiddle where I tried two different methods: http://jsfiddle.net/dqkzV/2/. There is also another answer on here which claims to work, but doesn't seem to work for me (2nd method on my jsFiddle): [jQuery tooltip onClick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941931/jquery-tooltip-onclick). With both methods I tried, the tooltip still appears on mouseover, when it is only supposed to appear on click.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first method is just adding a qTip to the `<body>` when the `.clickme` button is clicked, although I do not understand why it seems to not be added and then sometimes appears on mouseover.

The second method is using the [show syntax from qTip 1.0](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#show) but you have included qtip 2 as the library in the fiddle. The [qTip 2 show API](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/api/events/#show) is very different.

The following should show the tooltip when the button is clicked.

#### JavaScript (jQuery)

```
$('.clickme').qtip({
    content: 'Hello 2nd Test',
    show: 'click'
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed the fact that the second method was using qTip 1.0. The first method was based on the source of the examples of the qTip 2 website - http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#growl. In another example (alert/confirm/prompt) they did something similar, but added qtip to a nonexistent element, $("<div />"). In any case, your solution works beautifully. Thanks again.